# Einstein notation - Diagonal matrix

Tags: summation, notation

This may be very easy, but I'm not seeing it.

I am using Einstein notation to write a proof of a theorem in classical mechanics. I have a $3\times 3$ matrix $I$. After a diagonalisation process I reach a matrix $I'$, which is diagonal. I am tempted to write $I'_{ij} = J_i\delta_{ij}$ but of course in the RHS I have a summation. How do I get rid of that summation and still use a Kronecker delta to show that if $i\neq j$ then $I'_{ij}=0$?

Comment: You may want to cross-post this on the physics stackexchange, where they're more used to Einstein notation.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks for the recommendation, however they don't usually tend to answer questions like mine because they are not "too general", and also they close these sort of questions unfortunately.

Comment: You could just make a note next to that line in your work like $$I'_{ij} = J_i\delta_{ij}\tag{summation not implied}$$

Comment: [Here’s](http://mathoverflow.net/a/55829) a series of matrix operations that “convert” a vector into a diagonal matrix. You’ll need to figure out a way to represent the $E_i$ matrices in Einstein notation to use it, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We could define the following tensor:
$$ \delta_{\mu\nu}^i = \begin{cases}
1, \ \mu=\nu=i\\
0, \ \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$

Then the diagonal matrix $I'_{\mu\nu} = \delta^i_{\mu\nu} c_i$. In addition, it is possible to define $\delta_{\mu\nu}^i$ using the Kronecker delta as: $\delta_{\mu\nu}^i = \delta_\mu^i \delta_\nu^\epsilon \delta_\epsilon$, where $\delta_\epsilon$ - the vector with all elements are equal to one.

One could notice that $\delta_\epsilon$ (as $\delta_{\mu\nu}^i$) depends on the chosen basis.

Comment: Hi, I don't see why this is true: $\delta^i_{\mu\nu}=\delta^i_\mu\delta^\epsilon_\nu\delta_\epsilon$.

The right hand side decouples $\nu$ from the other two indices.

Answer (score 0):

Well if any previous step if you have any matrix say A whose diagonal component is equal to the diagonal component of I'.

I' = A ⊗ δ (Hadamard or elementwise product of A and δ (=Identity matrix))

More on indicial form of Hadamard equation can be found here:
[1]: [Is it possible to write the Hadamard product of two matrices in tensor notation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649313/is-it-possible-to-write-the-hadamard-product-of-two-matrices-in-tensor-notation)