# Is it possible to write the Hadamard product of two matrices in tensor notation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, tensors

Say I have two $4 \times 4$ matrices $(A^{\alpha \beta})$ and $(B^{\mu\nu})$ and want to compute the Hadamard (entry-wise) product. Is there an elegant way of writing this down in the common component, i.e. tensor, notation? Would it be something like $A^{\alpha \beta} B^{\alpha \beta}$ or is that not sufficient? Would this lead to conflicts with Einsteins summation convention?

Comment: $(A,B) \to \sum_{ij} (e_i^T A e_j) (e_i^T B e_j) e_i e_j^T $

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you aren't using the summation convention then $C^{\alpha\beta}=A^{\alpha\beta}B^{\alpha\beta}$ is fine.

If you are using the summation convention then $A^{\alpha\beta}B^{\alpha\beta}$ means

$$\sum_{\alpha\beta}A^{\alpha\beta}B^{\alpha\beta}$$

which is a scalar rather than a matrix. In this case the thing to do is to define a new tensor $\delta^\alpha_{\;\beta\gamma}$ such that

$$\delta^\alpha_{\;\beta\gamma}=\begin{cases}
1&\text{if}\;\alpha=\beta=\gamma\\
0&\text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}$$

in your basis. Then define $C^{\alpha\beta}=\delta^\alpha_{\;\gamma\delta}\delta^\beta_{\;\eta\phi}A^{\gamma\eta}B^{\delta\phi}$.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Very elegant, thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to write that new tensor you introduce as a combination of Kronecker deltas without messing with the summation convention?

Comment: @MaxD If you're not using the summation convention then $\delta^\alpha_{\;\beta\gamma}=\delta^\alpha_{\;\beta}\delta^\alpha_{\;\gamma}$.

Comment: @OscarCunningham That's what I wanted to exclude by saying "without", probably could've been more clear.

Comment: @MaxD If you're using the summation convention then using a combination of $\delta$s and contractions will always yield an even number of indices. Another point is that $\delta^\alpha_{\;\beta}$ is basis invariant whereas $\delta^\alpha_{\;\gamma\delta}$ is not.

Comment: Now I'm not as ashamed of ChatGPT for being [confused about this subject](https://chat.openai.com/share/29a6039a-806a-4440-8e70-20438bb58b7e).   Summing convention (aka einstein notation) is not incompatible: `torch.einsum('ij,ij->ij', A, B)` performs an elementwise multiplication, yet Pytorch's `einsum` uses summing convention.

Comment: I've added a [stand-alone answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4738353/59510) that also takes my comment further.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you include both sides of the equation, Einstein notation works well here:

- Variables occurring on only one side of the equation are summed.
- Variables occurring on both sides of the equation are not.

With this convention, $C^{\alpha\beta}=A^{\alpha\beta}B^{\alpha\beta}$ is perfectly clear.

This is the convention used by Numpy, PyTorch, and, I assume, Tensorflow.  You can compute an elementwise multiplication with `np.einsum('ij,ij->ij', A, B)` or `torch.einsum('ij,ij->ij', A, B)`. Since Tensorflow's einsum has a similar notation, I assume it would also work there.

Therefore, contrary to [Oscar's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1651828/59510), an elementwise multiplication can be represented even when summing convention (that is, Einstein notation) is assumed. There is no need to introduce delta notation here.

Now I'm not as ashamed of ChatGPT for being [confused about this subject](https://chat.openai.com/share/29a6039a-806a-4440-8e70-20438bb58b7e).

Comment: "Now I'm not as ashamed of ChatGPT" , but you should be it.

Comment: @Peter The point is that humans are struggling with this question. Why would we expect a robot to be able to answer it?  Also, I never said I was unashamed of ChatGPT, only *less* ashamed.